# Android Room Persistence Library - How to find entities with ids contained in list of ids?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-room

I am trying to do the following query in my DAO.

```
   @Query("SELECT * FROM objects WHERE obj_id IN :ids")
   List<Object> queryObjects(List<String> ids);
```

It gives me this compile-time error:

```
Error: no viable alternative at input 'SELECT * FROM objects WHERE obj_id IN :ids'
```

Both `List<String> ids` as well as `String... ids` and `Sring[] ids` don't work. However, since I don't know how many ids I will have in compile-time and therefore, I need a list/array and not varargs.

How can I make this SQL query work?

Comment: Try `String[]`.

Comment: Didn't work :/. Actually I tested again and not even String... (vararg) is working. I think something weird had happened before and somehow it compiled.

Comment: @YCF_L, what do you mean by `nativeQuery`? I didn't find anything like this related to Room Persistence Library

Comment: its my bad i thought you are using spring

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You need parentheses:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM objects WHERE obj_id IN (:ids)")
List<Object> queryObjects(List<String> ids);
```

(and FWIW, I filed [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72279770) to try to get a better error message here)

Comment: This link will improve your answer hope you can accept it [Passing a collection of arguments](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data.html#query-collection-args)

Comment: Will it work fine. In case of List<Integer>??? 
Example:
 @Query("SELECT * FROM objects WHERE obj_id IN (:ids)")
List<Object> queryObjects(List<Integer> ids);

Comment: @user2980181: I would expect that to work, though I have not tried that particular combination personally.

Comment: Just wondering, is it possible to return the list od Objects in the order as the list of ids?

Comment: @DanielSpiess: I do not know of any SQLite SQL syntax for that. I can't rule it out, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can set either list of input or array of input.

and then make a query like this

> e.g. **String[] ids or List ids**
>
> > Query = **@Query("select * from objects where obj_id in (:ids)")**