# Room - Select query with IN condition?

Tags: android, sqlite, select, android-room, sql-in

Is it possible to use SQLite's `IN` condition with Room?

I'm trying to select a list of items from my database where the value of a certain column (in this case a `TEXT` column) matches any one of a set of filter values. That's pretty easily done in SQL and SQLite, by my knowledge, just by adding an `IN` condition to your `SELECT` statement ([see here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/in.php)). However, I can't seem to make it work with Room.

I keep getting this error:

```
Error:(70, 25) error: no viable alternative at input 'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE column IN :filterValues'
```

(where the input to the DAO `@Query`-annotated method is called `filterValues`)

I have tried three different methods now:

1. Passing the argument as a `List<String>`
2. Passing the argument as a `String[]`
3. And lastly passing the argument as simply a `String`, but formatted as `(value_1, value_2, ..., value_n)`

The last one in particular should work easily, as it will (or at least, it should) directly translate to `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE column IN (value_1, value_2, ..., value_n)`, which is the exact way you would manually write out the `SELECT` if you were just accessing the database directly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48370198/115145

Comment: @CommonsWare Yea, that would have fixed my issue immediately. Unfortunately, I never ran across that question in all of my searches since I was looking specifically for information regarding Room and `SELECT` with an `IN` condition (which aren't actually mentioned in that question).

Comment: Note that all of those things are mentioned in [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48370045/115145).

Answer (score 156, accepted):

So as I was preparing to submit this, I double-checked a bunch of the stuff I had looked up previously and found the thing I had somehow missed and would have saved this question from being necessary.

As it turns out, both of these options:

1. Passing the argument as a `List<String>`
2. Passing the argument as a `String[]`

are viable (and you can replace `String` with any type the database can represent, such as `char` or `int`), you simply need to change the syntax in the `@Query` annotation from this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE column IN :filterValues")
```

to this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE column IN (:filterValues)")
```

Easy as pie, right?

Note that the third method above (passing the argument as simply a `String`, but formatted as `(value_1, value_2, ..., value_n)`) does not appear to be supported by Room, but that's probably not a bad thing, since that's the hard way.

Since I already had the whole thing typed out, I figured I would leave the question up in case other people are have as much difficulty finding this solution as I did and stumble upon this question.

Comment: Any way to get this to work with custom classes? eg. enums.  It doesn't seem to use TypeConverter to convert lists of custom classes.

Comment: Not sure if I understand entirely - you want to search through a collection/list of custom objects? Custom objects/classes can be used in Room with `@TypeConverter`s, but that's used to convert an entire table (or a subset of that table's columns) into a class (or vice-a-versa). SQL queries search/index individual columns, which must still be SQL-supported data types (String, Int, etc.).

What you can do instead of passing a list of custom objects is have multiple arguments corresponding to certain fields in those objects, which each map to a single column.

Comment: eg `@Query("SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE day IN (:days)") fun getAgenda(days: List<DayOfWeek>)` where `enum class DayOfWeek { MON, TUES, ... }`.  A `TypeConverter` can be used to query/fetch `DayOfWeek` in all other contexts, except (it seems) for `IN`

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is the the `TypeConverter` doesn't know how to parse the List. Try making a converter that accepts a List<DayOfWeek> and spits out a List<whatever the database stores> (I'm assuming it's an int or string). Alternatively, just build that List yourself and send that as the argument.

Comment: Looks like this may have been fixed in 2.1.0-alpha07 :) https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122066791

Answer (score 56):

Hi you can use this query:

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid IN(:userIds)")
 public abstract List findByIds(int[] userIds);
```

or

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid IN(:userIds)")
 public abstract List findByIds(List<Integer> userIds);
```

Comment: useful for me. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 19):

Similarly to above answers in `Kotlin` you can use `vararg` instead of `array` or `list`:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid IN (:userIds)")
fun getUsers(vararg userIds: Int): List<User>?
```

and use it like `repository.getUsers(1, 2, 3)`.

If needed, to convert `vararg` to `list` see https://proandroiddev.com/kotlins-vararg-and-spread-operator-4200c07d65e1 (use `*`: `format(output, *params)`).