# How can I turn a list of strings into LIKE clauses in a Room Query?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I have a table called `games` that has a column called `platforms`, which contains a list of platform abbreviations. This is a list of all the platforms that specific game came out on. Here's an example of one of the cells in `platforms`:

`AMI,GG,SNES,CPC,AST,C64,SPEC,MAC,PS2,NES,3DO,ARC,XBGS,PS3N,PC,IPHN,DSI,HALC,PSPN,ANDR,`

The user can choose any number of platforms they wish to view games for. For example, they may choose to see games for the following platforms:

`SNES, MAC, PC`

So I need a way to programmatically construct a Room query that would find games in the selected platforms. I need to somehow generate an arbitrary number of LIKE clauses and inject them into the query. I tried the following, but it returned no results:

```
private fun fetchLikeClauses(platformIndices: MutableSet<Int>): String {
    val sb = StringBuilder()

    // Game.platforms LIKE '%XONE%' OR Game.platforms LIKE '%PC%'

    for (platformIndex in platformIndices) {
        sb.append("platforms LIKE '%${allPlatforms[platformIndex].abbreviation}%'")
        sb.append(" OR ")
    }
    return sb.toString().removeSuffix(" OR ")
}




@Query("SELECT * FROM Game WHERE :likeClauses")
fun getGames(likeClauses: String): DataSource.Factory<Int, Game>
```

Here's another thing I tried, but it didn't work for some reason:
[Passing in a string to use as part of a Room query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60559971/passing-in-a-string-to-use-as-part-of-a-room-query)

I'm guessing RawQuery would work for this? Is there another way though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [@RawQuery](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RawQuery) and build [SimpleSQLiteQuery](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/sqlite/db/SimpleSQLiteQuery) dynamically:

In dao:

```
@RawQuery(observedEntities = [Game::class])
fun getGames(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): DataSource.Factory<Int, Game>
```

Here `buildFinalQuery` function:

```
fun buildFinalQuery(platforms: List<String>): SimpleSQLiteQuery {
    val selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Game"

    val finalQuery = selectQuery + platforms.joinToString(prefix = " WHERE ", separator = " OR ") {
        "Game.platforms LIKE '%$it%'"
    }

    return SimpleSQLiteQuery(finalQuery)
}

val query = buildFinalQuery("SNES", "MAC", "PC")
dao.getGames(query)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked great with one simple edit: `@RawQuery(observedEntities = [Game::class])`

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution does not work because Room automatically escapes your generated string to prevent a SQL Injection.

To solve your problem you should use the SQL-In operator.
[Read more about the SQL-IN operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Your DAO could look like this

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM Game WHERE platforms IN(:platformsToShow)")
 fun getGames(platformsToShow: Array<String>): DataSource.Factory<Int, Game>
```

[Here is a StackOverflow Post with the same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48406229/3649738)

**NOTE THIS SOLUTION ONLY WORKS WITH EXACT SEARCH RESULTS**
To support upper and lower case you could use the SQL `UPPER` or `LOWER` function.

```
SELECT * FROM Game
WHERE UPPER(platforms) IN ('AMI', 'SNES', 'PC');
```

Comment: IN and LIKE is not same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1865377/4699509

Comment: You're probably right about the SQL injection thing. But `IN` doesn't work here because we need to search through a list of platforms. We're not looking for exact matches.

Comment: @GavinWright you're right SQL-IN needs a exact search result.
But if you only want to consider upper and lower case, you can also use UPPER/LOWER.  

```
SELECT * FROM Game
WHERE UPPER(platforms) IN ('AMI', 'SNES', 'PC');
```

Comment: The case isn't the problem. We have two lists: 1) each cell in the `platforms` column of the database is a list, and 2) the user-selected platforms also comprise a list. So we need to search list 1 to see if it contains any instances of the items in list 2, and we need to do that for every row in the database.