# Passing in a string to use as part of a Room query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Why does this not work in Room?:

```
val dataSourceFactory =
    database.gameDao.getGames("Game.platforms LIKE '%XONE%'")

@Query("SELECT * FROM Game WHERE :likeClause")
fun getGames(likeClause: String): DataSource.Factory<Int, Game>
```

But this does?:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Game WHERE Game.platforms LIKE '%XONE%'")
fun getGames(): DataSource.Factory<Int, Game>
```

Is there any way to pass in a string that can stand in as part of the query?

EDIT: I know this isn't the correct way to form a single LIKE clause, but I'm actually trying to pass in multiple LIKE clauses. So I want a way to inject text directly into the query, but Room doesn't seem to want me to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44288296/4168607

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about dynamic SQL and I dont think this is possible with room. what would work is

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Game WHERE Game.platforms LIKE :likeClause1 AND Game.publisher LIKE :likeClause2")
fun getGames(likeClause1: String, likeClause2: String): DataSource.Factory<Int, Game>
```

and you can use either `AND` or `OR` as needed and if you want to ignore one of the like clauses just pass an empty string

Comment: Thanks. I ended up figuring this out by using a RawQuery (although your answer would have worked if I knew how many LIKE clauses I needed ahead of time): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60559869/how-can-i-turn-a-list-of-strings-into-like-clauses-in-a-room-query