# android Room, how to delete multiple rows in the table by id list

Tags: android-room, sql-delete

Having a Android Room with three tables `timestamp`, `index`, `details`, and all three have

```
@PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Int = 0
```

having `fun clearDataByID(idList: List<Int>)`  to clear data from all three tables by the `id` in the `idList`

Dao as:

```
@Dao
interface DataDAO {


@Transaction
fun clearDataByID(idList: List<Int>) {
    deleteDataInTimestamp(idList)
    deleteDataIndex(idList)
    deleteDataDetails(idList)
}

@Query("delete from timestamp where id in :idList")
fun deleteDataInTimestamp(idList: List<Int>)

@Query("delete from index where id in :idList")
fun deleteDataIndex(idList: List<Int>)

@Query("delete from details where id in :idList")
fun deleteDataDetails(idList: List<Int>)
}
```

but it gets compiler error (similar for all three)

```
error: no viable alternative at input 'delete from timestamp where id in :idList'
public abstract void deleteDataInTimestamp(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

if delete by single id it worked.

How to delete by a list of ids?

```
@Query("delete from timestamp where id = :id")
fun deleteSingleTimestamp(id: Int)
```

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48370198/10805404)? It explains how to do a `SELECT` with a list of ids.

Comment: thanks @SimonDoppler for point it out! it is the `obj_id IN (:ids)` missing the bracket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just extending the answer given by @lannyf

```
@Query("delete from timestamp where id in (:idList)")
fun deleteDataInTimestamp(idList: List<Int>)
```

this could be written in this way also

```
@Query("delete from timestamp where id = :idList")
fun deleteDataInTimestamp(idList: List<Int>)
```

PS: edit queue was full

Comment: The first way works! However the second one doesn't work
The error is `near ",": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: DELETE FROM product WHERE id = ?,?`

Answer (score 57):

Thanks Simon points to the similar question, it should be done like:

```
@Query("delete from timestamp where id in (:idList)")
fun deleteDataInTimestamp(idList: List<Int>)
```

Comment: is this doable with a String list?

Comment: The braces are off in your answer. But thanks it works. For strings too

Comment: What could be the maximum idList Size?

Comment: crashing for large data